# how do I access a HTML element from javascript using id,the html element belongs to another html document

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Continued from the question title:

also the other html document is loaded in the parent using AJAX,like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'calender.aspx',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $(".mainBar").html(data);
        }
    });
```

I need to get a table from calender.aspx which has id 'tableID';

Answer (score 0):

From within your success callback:

```
$(data).find("#tableID");
```

Comment: `data` will be a string in the OP's code. Perhaps you meant `$("#tableId", $(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you appear to be inserting the document into your document via the line `$(".mainBar").html(data);`. That being the case, you can then just get it via `$("#tableId")` once you've done that:

```
$(".mainBar").html(data);
var theTable = $("#tableId");
```

If your goal is *not* to append everything, but to do something else, you can build up a disconnected DOM tree by doing `$(data)`, and then search it via `find`:

```
var theTable = $(data).find("#tableId");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you can just use `.load`. However, you would do this:

```
var $table;

$.ajax({
        url: 'calender.aspx',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $table = $(data).find('#tableID');
           $(".mainBar").empty().append($table);
        }
    });
```

Same thing with `.load`:

```
var $table;
$('.mainBar').load('calendar.aspx #tableID', function(html) {
   $table = $(html).find('#tableID');
});
```

Comment: hmm but how to store that element in an javascript var?

P.S:Plz endure my naiveness

Comment: updated my answer. i thought you were only interested in appending #tableID, not referencing it as a variable.